# iOS resetting an apps location settings to while in app after I manually set it to always

Tags: ios, permission, geolocation

My wife's iPhone has an app installed (Home Assistant Companion app if it matters). I went into the iOS settings, and for the location permission it asks for I set it to "Always", however, it keeps reverting the location settings from location Always to While using the app.

She doesn't often open the app, and I'm *guessing* maybe that's why it's being reverted.

Is there a way I can stop iOS reverting the location setting?